# See logs of a command inside a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, logs, services

I have a systemd service that runs ngrok.

```
[Unit]
Description=Ngrok
After=network.service

[Service]
type=simple
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
ExecStart=/snap/bin/ngrok http 4000 --host-header="localhost:4000"
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The status of this service:

```
● ngrok.service - Ngrok
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ngrok.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-04-23 14:30:57 UTC; 7min ago
   Main PID: 24333 (ngrok)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 4435)
     CGroup: /system.slice/ngrok.service
             ‣ 24333 /snap/ngrok/56/ngrok http 3000 --host-header=localhost:4000

Apr 23 14:30:57 pi-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Ngrok.
```

However, I have to see the output of ngrok to get the url. How can I see the output of the **ngrok** command like this from a systemd service.

```
~> ngrok http 4000 --host-header="localhost:4000"
    ngrok                                                                                                                                       (Ctrl+C to quit)                                                                                                                                                            Session Status                online
    Account                       Amod Amatya (Plan: Free)
    Version                       3.0.2
    Region                        Europe (eu)
    Latency                       27.47694ms
    Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
    Forwarding                    https://xyz-testing.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:4000                                                                                                                                                                                                    Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                                  0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

PS. journalctl also does not show the full logs of the command.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to see the output of ngrok to get the url.

There has to be a better way! That's an important operational property and should not just be visible through stdout. I'm certain `Ngrok` has some way of reading that from a running service. I've never used ngrok, but I understand it's some kind of port-forwarding service, and you can [query your active endpoints](https://ngrok.com/docs/api#api-endpoints) rather easily using

```bsh
curl \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer {API_KEY}" \
    -H "Ngrok-Version: 2" \
    https://api.ngrok.com/endpoints
```

> journalctl also does not show the full logs of the command.

Then your ngrok doesn't log what you want. It's simple as that: the stdout of commands started from a service file are what you see with `journalct -u ngrok.service`. If it's not in there, it has not been printed.